# Development Questions for Google Analytics

Tags: discussion, migration, moderation

Stemming from [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114161/google-analytics-additem-for-multiple-skus-in-one-call?noredirect=1#comment28264348_19114161) on [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53667/google-analytics-additem-for-multiple-skus-in-one-call), I'd like to start an open discussion with the moderators on how to handle Google Analytics questions. Personally, I strongly disagree with the decision made on the question that I linked. I've also seen [many](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53376/google-analytics-e-commerce-tracking) [other](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/tracking-outgoing-links-with-google-analytics-events) [questions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50966/is-there-any-way-to-get-data-from-google-analytics-per-page-visit) that run into this same problem... and these are just a few of the ones I remember off of the top of my head.

The problem lies in that the community sees "Google Analytics" and automatically assumes that it must be done in the interface and isn't a coding problem. While I agree there are questions that get posted onto SO that are indeed interface questions, it seems like there are a lot that are falsely identified and moved to pro webmasters.

So I ask, what exactly are the qualifications for having a Google Analytics question on StackOverflow vs. Pro Webmasters? In my mind if it has anything to do with the implementation or JavaScript portions it should go on StackOverflow. Is that a correct assumption here?

Comment: I'm assuming by Stack Exchange, you mean Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Bart - You'd be correct, thanks!

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable either way but it's worth noting that it was mod-migrated to a site that is not on the list, which would normally imply the webmasters people are happy to receive this type of question, without prejudice etc etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

I too wish to be enlightened about this.  It seems that there is no clear line drawn in the sand between report vs. implementation questions and it seems mods have different opinions about it and even when you try to explain to them (I do analytics for a living...) what type of question it is.. roll of the dice whether or not they will agree or just stick with a decision based on their own understanding.   GA is an analytics tool, but in order to implement it, you must code it. The most common method is javascript.  Implementation is *clearly* a coding issue.  And it's really frustrating to see something so clearly a coding issue be shunted over to webmasters because someone doesn't understand the question - especially after attempts have been made to clarify it.  And what rubs salt in the wound is that there's a frakking google-analytics tag on SO with like 4.4k posts for it. And yet many times I have seen people just say "Oh, GA, automatically move to webmasters, regardless." If that were really the case, then why hasn't *all* of the questions been moved there?

If nothing else, even if I disagree with GA questions being shunted over to webmasters, I would at least like to see some consistency in mod decisions about it.